# How to Generate an AES Key using a Local Private Key and a Remote Public Key in Java?

Tags: java, encryption

Hi I was reading the following Wikipedia article on Public Key Cryptography
[Public Key Cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)

I saw this picture too which shows how to generate a symmetric key cipher using your Private Key and the OTHER persons Public Key.
[Generate Symmetric Key/Shared Secret](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Public_key_shared_secret.svg)

I already know how to exchange the public keys between the parties however I was wondering If it were possible to implement the procedure in the picture using the Java Programming Language.

The Private and Public Keys used would be generated using RSA and the Key/Shared Secret to be generated would be a Symmetric Key for a Symmetric Cipher (I want to use AES-128)

I understand the theory behind this but am unsure how to implement it in Java properly, any ideas or help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`KeyAgreement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyAgreement.html) and algorithm [`"DiffieHellman"`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyAgreement). Note that you need Java 8 for 2048 bit key sizes, Java 7 and below are stuck on 1024 (unless you install the [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) provider).

Or you can go for the `"ECDH"` algorithm, but beware that takes a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it but how come KeyAgreement class doesn't have an RSA algorithm and only a DiffieHellman algorithm ?

Comment: You can use the RSA algorithm using the `Cipher` class. In that case you simply encrypt the key you want to share with the public key and decrypt it with the private key (of the server). This won't however give you perfect forward secrecy; i.e. the ciphertext created by using the session key can be read if the RSA private key ever becomes known. Note that - on the other hand - DH may not contain authentication and is therefore usually susceptible to man in the middle attacks. Take a look at TLS to see how this can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks owlstead using that I was able to write the following code which generates RSA keys and then Tries to link the private keys together with the opposing public key using DiffieHellman

```
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class AESKeGenFromRSA
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        // Generate RSA KeyPair for Alice
        Cipher alice_rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        // Get RSA KeyPairGenerator Object Instance
        KeyPairGenerator alice_gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        // Generate RSA Assymetric KeyPair
        KeyPair alice_pair = alice_gen.generateKeyPair();
        // Extract Public Key
        PublicKey alice_pub = alice_pair.getPublic();
        // Extract Private Key
        PrivateKey alice_pvt = alice_pair.getPrivate();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Alice Public: " + alice_pub);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Alice Private: " + alice_pvt);

        // Generate RSA KeyPair for Bob
        Cipher bob_rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        // Get RSA KeyPairGenerator Object Instance
        KeyPairGenerator bob_gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        // Generate RSA Assymetric KeyPair
        KeyPair bob_pair = bob_gen.generateKeyPair();
        // Extract Public Key
        PublicKey bob_pub = bob_pair.getPublic();
        // Extract Private Key
        PrivateKey bob_pvt = bob_pair.getPrivate();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Bob Public: " + bob_pub);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Bob Private: " + bob_pvt);

        // Create KeyAgreement for Alice
        KeyAgreement alice_agreement =     KeyAgreement.getInstance("DiffieHellman");
        alice_agreement.init(alice_pvt);
        alice_agreement.doPhase(bob_pub, true);
        byte[] alice_secret = alice_agreement.generateSecret();
        SecretKeySpec alice_aes = new SecretKeySpec(alice_secret, "AES");

        // Create KeyAgreement for Bob
        KeyAgreement bob_agreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DiffieHellman");
        bob_agreement.init(bob_pvt);
        bob_agreement.doPhase(alice_pub, true);
        byte[] bob_secret = bob_agreement.generateSecret();
        SecretKeySpec bob_aes = new SecretKeySpec(bob_secret, "AES");

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(alice_aes.equals(bob_aes));
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (NoSuchPaddingException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (InvalidKeyException e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
}
}
```

This is the exception that gets thrown when I try to run the program. I understand why this is happening but I'm a little unsure how to fix it.

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl
at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.chooseProvider(KeyAgreement.java:398)
at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.init(KeyAgreement.java:464)
at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.init(KeyAgreement.java:435)
at AESKeGenFromRSA.main(AESKeGenFromRSA.java:45)
```

It seems that PrivateKey objects are not a valid argument to the KeyAgreement.init(Key key) function, Any ideas would be appreciated ...

Comment: Never mind I solved it by changing KeyPairGenerator alice_gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA"); to this KeyPairGenerator alice_gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DiffieHellman"); for both instances of KeyPairGenerator